# How to check Internet connection while uploading and Downloading is happening in the Mobile

Tags: android

I am doing heavy downloading and Uploading in my project. I am checking the Internet connection before the Downloading and Uploading start. but their is some small Issue Means when I start the uploading and downloading process and while proccessing if Internet connection is gone then how to track that.

Comment: You will get an `IOException`

Comment: Thanks Adil, OK So I have to catch this exception and tell the user to Download Again.

Comment: I think you can do it using a try and catch rite?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to manifest file .

use the below method to check internet connection

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {    
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
      context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo  = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null; 

}
```